# C string struct with mem allocation included

Tags: c, char, malloc

I am working with a bunch of strings for logging. I want to refactor my code and make a new struct that combines the char, its length and allocated size. The idea is to make my internal string operations smoother and the code nicer to read, whilst assigning each string its own max allocated memory to keep the usage to a minimum but prevent stack overflow. I made this simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct 
{
  char *str;
  int size;
  int max;
} Text;

void defText(Text *text, int max)
{
  text->str=(char*) malloc(max * sizeof(char));
  text->str="";
  text->max=max;
}


int main() {
    Text *a;
    defText(a,50);
    a->str="Test all you want";
    printf("OUT: %s %zu %lu",a->str,strlen(a->str),sizeof(a->str));
    return 0;
}
```

The function defText initializes and allocates memory. However, when I check the sizeof the char in my struct, I always get 8, no matter what I set in defText. Is this kind of struct handling strings and their properties together even possible? If so, what is wrong here?

Comment: "the sizeof the char in my struct" I assume you mean `sizeof str`? `str` is a pointer, which is 8 bytes on a x64 system, that size will never change. `sizeof` does not return the amount of memory it points to, you need to track that yourself.

Comment: Furthermore `text->str=(char*) malloc(max * sizeof(char)); text->str="";` is incorrect. That creates a memory leak by overwriting the pointer returned by `malloc` to a pointer to the string literal `""`. `""` is a string containing only the `NUL` terminator `'\0'`. Writing to a string literal is undefined behavior in C. Even if it wasn't, `text->str` now only points to one byte, any multi-character string you write there would overflow the memory area. Any single character you write there will overwrite the `NUL` terminator, invalidating that memory as a C string.

Comment: `Text *a; defText(a,50);` is incorrect. You haven't allocated any memory for `a` yet, so when you dereference it in `defText` with `text->`, you're invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems in your code, this is an example that cleans up these problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct 
{
  char *str;
  // you could use size to keep track of the strlen. That's particularly
  // desirable if you find yourself calling strlen "a lot", since that
  // function recalculates the length every time it's called
  int size;
  int max;
} Text;

void defText(Text *text, int max)
{
  // no need to cast the return of malloc. In fact, sizeof(char) is defined by
  // the standard to be 1 so you could take that out also.
  text->str=malloc(max * sizeof(char));
  // `=` is not the proper way to write strings in C, you must use strcpy
  // or something similar. It looks like here you're simply trying to
  // create an empty string.
  //text->str="";
  // per @JohnBollinger's comment, the best thing to do here to create
  // an empty string is simply set to the first byte to the NUL
  // terminator.
  text->str[0] = '\0';
  text->max=max;
}


int main() {
    Text a;  // store this in automatic memory, now the object exists without having to malloc
    defText(&a,50); // Use & to pass the address of a to defText

    // as mentioned, this is not the proper way to write data to a string in
    // C. What you've done here is create a memory leak and point a.str to
    // the string literal "Test all you want". Use strcpy (or similar) to
    // write that string into the data you actually malloc'ed (using the dot
    // operator now since `a` is no longer a pointer)
    //a->str="Test all you want";
    strcpy(a.str, "Test all you want");
    // a.str is a pointer, and will always be 8 bytes on your system no matter
    // the size of the memory it points to
    printf("OUT: %s %zu %zu",a.str,strlen(a.str),sizeof(a.str));

    // clean up allocated memory. Since we're about to exit, there's
    // really no need to do this here (the OS will reclaim all allocated
    // memory when the process ends), but if you're writing a more
    // involved, long-running program, you need to be sure to handle
    // memory allocations and deallocations appropriately as needed
    free(a.str);

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bdnWGY18r)

Comment: `text->str[0] = '\0';` would be an alternative way to make the allocated data represent an empty string.  That is not equivalent to zeroing the whole space, but it's a bit more efficient.  If zeroing the whole space is desired then allocating the memory with `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` would provide for that automatically, and also would be more efficient than separate `malloc()` and `memset()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I agree, both good points. Never really considered `calloc` being more efficient that `malloc` and `memset`, but yeah that makes sense too since you're doing it all with one call.

Comment: @yano Thank you for the very extensive answer. I knew the -> notation gives me a pointer, but somehow got distracted since I seemingly got partly correct output back, but now that you point it out, it was just two wrongs that didn't compensate each other at all - I guess I shouldn't program that late :)

Answer (score 0):

The
`a->str` 
is pointer .
the correct answer is
`sizeof(*(a->str))`

Comment: `*(a->str)` is equivalent to `(a->str)[0]`, the first data element that `a->str` points to. In this case, that's a `char`, so `sizeof(*(a->str))` simply returns 1, not the length of the string. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sve8zo994)